# How to fetch video/audio tracks in chunks

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have a video and several separate audio tracks. All audio tracks are in different languages. I'd like to give users an option to switch seamlessly beetwen audio tracks.

I found solution with MSE API how to do it on Stackoverflow. It works very nice and smooth except one thing. It loads full video, audio tracks once the user clicks the play button.

How to load video/audio data in chunks so that it stayed well synced while playing?

Works well but loads full video/audio tracks after user hits the play button

```
const mimeVideoCodec = 'video/webm; codecs="vp9"';
const mimeAudioCodec = 'audio/webm; codecs=opus';

const getFileBuffer = async (link: string) => {
  const response = await fetch(link);
  return response.arrayBuffer();
};

const waitForEvent = async (target: MediaSource | SourceBuffer, event: string) => {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    target.addEventListener(event, res, { once: true });
  });
};

interface UseVideoStreaming {
  videoElement: HTMLVideoElement | null;
  checkboxElement: HTMLInputElement | null;
  isPlaying: boolean;
  url: string;
}

export const useVideoStreaming = ({ url, videoElement, checkboxElement }: UseVideoStreaming) => {
  const buffer = useCallback(async () => {
    if (!videoElement || !checkboxElement) {
      return null;
    }

    const fileBuffer = await getFileBuffer(url);

    const originalAudioBuffer = await getFileBuffer(VoiceoverOriginal);
    const translatedAudioBuffer = await getFileBuffer(VoiceoverTranslated);

    const source = new MediaSource();

    videoElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(source);

    await waitForEvent(source, 'sourceopen');

    const videoBuffer = source.addSourceBuffer(mimeVideoCodec);
    videoBuffer.appendBuffer(fileBuffer);

    const audioBuffer = source.addSourceBuffer(mimeAudioCodec);
    audioBuffer.appendBuffer(checkboxElement.checked ? translatedAudioBuffer : originalAudioBuffer);
    await Promise.all([waitForEvent(audioBuffer, 'updateend'), waitForEvent(videoBuffer, 'updateend')]);

    source.endOfStream();

    checkboxElement.onchange = async () => {
      audioBuffer.remove(0, source.duration);
      await waitForEvent(audioBuffer, 'updateend');
      audioBuffer.appendBuffer(checkboxElement.checked ? translatedAudioBuffer : originalAudioBuffer);
      await waitForEvent(audioBuffer, 'updateend');
      source.endOfStream();
    };
  }, [checkboxElement, videoElement, url]);
```